# Docker - Laradock & React does not load live changes

Tags: reactjs, docker, laradock

I'm using a Macbook Pro with "macOS Mojave".
I have installed a Laravel project using Laradock (I followed their documentation for multiple projects installation), an recently I have installed a Laravel project with React but if I change something in the code, it won't load it to the interface unless I rebuild the docker container.

For example if I change something in a view (welcome.blade.php for example), the change appears immediately, but if I change something on App.js (react component) the change is not loaded until the container is rebuild. (I also run npm run dev/watch)

Do you have any ideas why is this happening? Can this be fixed?

Thank you in advance!

docker-compose.yml file:
https://ufile.io/51l5wx4g

Comment: Hi. Can you share your `Dockerfile` please? Are you copying the code to the image when you're building it or you're mounting your code to the container?

Comment: Hi Esteban, thanks for the reply. https://ufile.io/51l5wx4g here is the docker-compose.yml. I run the following docker command: docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin workspace and then docker-compose exec workspace bash to access the workspace.

Comment: Please edit your question and add it there. Thanks

Comment: I have added in the question also.. can be downloaded via link. I couldn't directly uploaded. Hope it's working. Thanks!